# Can I use reflection to inspect the code in a method?

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm playing around with the C# reflection API. I can easily load `Type` information of classes, methods etc. in an assembly, however, now I wonder how can I load and read the code inside a method?

Comment: What is the scenario that makes this useful? It breaks one of the fundamental tenants of OO which is encapsulation. But furthermore the code as IL is not really the same.

Comment: @DevelopingChris: If you're writing a debugger or code analysis tool, it may be useful to be able to load an assembly and analyze the body of a method. This is, in fact, what tools like FxCop do.

Comment: The target audience of .NET is US corporations (and secondarily perhaps some small businesses). If you could bypass .NET obfuscation, the (expensive to produce) software could easily fly into a competitor's fingertips.

Comment: @micahhoover Every statement in your comment is provably false both at the time of writing and now.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**Basic Answer:**

You can't with the reflection API (System.Reflection).

The reason is that the reflection api is designed to work on Metadata (Type of Classes, Name and Signature of Methods, ...) but not on the data level (which would be the IL-stream itself).

**Extended Answer:**

You can emit (but not read) IL with System.Reflection.Emit (e.g. ILGenerator Class).

Through `MethodInfo.GetMethodBody()` you can get the binary IL-stream for the implementation of a method. But thats usually completely useless by itself.

There are external libraries (like [Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil)) that you can use to read/modify/add/delete code inside a method.

Comment: Can't you refer to the method via a delegate, then create an ExpressionTree from the delegate and inspect the tree?

Comment: @Matt Greer: No. You cannot "reverse engineer" a delegate's method body into an expression tree.

Comment: @Matt: That's not going to give you the code *inside* the method, you'll just get a `MethodCallExpression` that gives you access to the same `MethodInfo` you could have gotten more directly with the reflection API.

Comment: No unless it could parse a binary IL stream which it cannot.

Comment: @Foxfire: Hi. I don't know if you'll see this, but if you do... Could you quote your sources when you say that the reflection API is designed to work on Metadata, not on the data level? I believe you ;) but I'd like to include this in my master thesis and I need some kind of reference for it. Thanks so much :)

Comment: No, I don't have any scientific-citeable sources for this ready. But it is A) obvious B) you can easily find MS employees blog posts on this.

Comment: @MattGreer There is a package for that https://nuget.org/packages/DelegateDecompiler/

Comment: `MethodInfo.GetMethodBody()` is not available on .NET Core, so to use IL-stream you can go with `MethodInfo.GetMetadataToken()` and `PEReader` (see full example here: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/4543#issuecomment-222689903)

Answer (score 23):

That depends on what you mean by "read the code." There are 4 forms of the code.

| Code Type | Can get with `Reflection` |
| --- | --- |
| The source code, i.e. the original C# or VB.NET | No |
| The symbolic IL code | No |
| The JITed assembly code | No |
| The IL bytes, i.e. the actual bytes that IL is compiled to | Yes |

Take a look at [`MethodBase.GetMethodBody()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbase.getmethodbody?view=net-5.0) for the last one. You can get the IL bytes, the local variables, exception frames etc.

Comment: `GetMethodBody()` is the closest you can get, I think.

Answer (score 9):

You *sort of* can.  The relevant function is [MethodBase.GetMethodBody](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getmethodbody.aspx).

It's not exactly the most useful API.  You can get some basic information about what's inside the method, and you can obtain the IL as a byte array.  That's about it.

There's a slightly better API in the [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) library, which exposes a `MethodDefinition` class with its own `MethodBody` implementation which contains actual `Instructions`, so you don't have to interpret the raw byte code.  Still, if you're looking to get C# code out of it à la Reflector, you're going to be sorely disappointed.  Also, Cecil isn't very well documented.

If you still want to try, then good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to provide an example of how one could explore the code inside a method. As others have explained, this can't be done easily using the native .NET Reflection API. However, using the [Mono.Reflection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.Reflection/) API, you can disassemble the code programmatically using the `GetInstructions()` method and inspect it at runtime.

For example, the following code inspects a method and computes the number of calls inside it. As a use case for such a code, say I am a teacher (which I am) and instruct my fellow students to program a given method without using any other method, then using this code in unit tests I can verify that the given constrain is respected.

```
public static class MethodInfoUtil
{
    public static int NbOfInnerCalls(this MethodInfo mi)
    {
        return mi.GetInstructions().Count(
            instruction => instruction.OpCode.FlowControl == FlowControl.Call);
    }
}
```

Example Console program:

```
class Program
{
    static int Add(int a, int b) => a + b;
    static int Doubling(int a) => Add(a, a);
    static int Quadrupling(int a) => Add(Add(a, a), Add(a, a));

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inner method calls");
        Console.WriteLine("        Add: {0}", ((Func<int, int, int>)Add).Method.NbOfInnerCalls());
        Console.WriteLine("   Doubling: {0}", ((Func<int, int>)Doubling).Method.NbOfInnerCalls());
        Console.WriteLine("Quadrupling: {0}", ((Func<int, int>)Quadrupling).Method.NbOfInnerCalls());
    }
}

// Output:
// Inner method calls
//         Add: 0
//    Doubling: 1
// Quadrupling: 3
```

Answer (score 1):

No
This is a feature slated for the next version of C#. You can use the CodeDom to get more info than reflection, but you cannot interrogate the parse tree yet.

Well there is always mono, in mono the compiler is a service, and you could get the parse trees at runtime.

The better question is why you want to?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there must be a way to achieve this: The .NET Reflector tool does this, too. Can't tell you how it's done there, though.

Comment: Why don't you reflect the reflector ;)

Comment: Reflector does not use reflection at least not in the .NET framework sense of reflection. It actually parses the PE file and dissembles the IL code from the .TEXT section. Then does some very smart and cool pattern matching to map/decompile the IL back to a target language.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to do this real-time, have a look at [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/). You can disassemble any .NET assembly (including the MS core DLLs) and see the code in your language of choice. This can be *very* educational.

**Update** Has anyone tried using Reflector on Reflector to figure out how this is done?

Comment: Note, this doesn't de-optimize the code. So if there was a compiler optimization done to the IL, it doesn't get returned to its original build source, but to a slightly less human written optimized version. Its a neat way to see what you could be doing most efficiently.

Comment: You can't use Reflector on Reflector.  Try it and see, you'll get a nice surprise.

Comment: Reflector is encrypted such that it can't reflect on itself, I think they used DotFuscator to do it.

Comment: I have tons of CIL code that crashes Reflector even without any obfuscation at all.  It isn't really possible to convert something to C# that could never have been written in that language in the first place.

Comment: @hoodaticus While I respect your answer, it's always possible to convert if your target language is Turing-complete. Now, whether or not it's easy, fast or a good idea in general is an entirely different discussion. :)

Comment: @DavidLively - how do you represent the calli instruction - calling native function pointer as a method - in C#?