# source code of anonymous method

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, anonymous-methods

How get a source code of anonymous method?

For example:

```
Func<Boolean> func = (() => DateTime.Now.Seconds % 2 == 0);

Console.WriteLine(GetSourceCode(func)); // must: DateTime.Now.Seconds % 2 == 0

String GetSourceCode<T>(Func<T> f) - ???
```

Comment: So `GetSourceCode` should return a `string`? Can i ask why you need it?

Comment: You can't, you can only get the `MSIL` and decompile if you like. That's not lambada expressions.

Comment: Yes GetSourceCode returns String.

Comment: I creating my unit test framework. I want to display source code of the failed tests.

Comment: I think this is a [similar question - c# Can I use reflection to inspect the code in a method?][1] 

Hope this will help you.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693881/c-sharp-can-i-use-reflection-to-inspect-the-code-in-a-method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can wrap it inside Expression and call ToString() on it and that will get you the source code.

Like this:

```
Expression<Func<Boolean>> func = (() => DateTime.Now.Seconds % 2 == 0);
var str = func.ToString();
```

The output str becomes 
`() => DateTime.Now.Seconds % 2 == 0`

Comment: +1 Awesome, didn't know about this! output is `() => DateTime.Now.Second % 2 == 0`

Comment: It's worth noting that technically this isn't a function.  If you really do have a function you can't ever get it's source code as a string.