# Determine if Assembly References Certain Classes

Tags: c#, .net, il

I'm trying to write a function that determines if an assembly contains any code that uses known references.  For example, determine if a given assembly uses the `Thread` class (as part of a method, an argument, etc).

I'm writing a program that consumes third-party assemblies.  I am already running the assemblies in a sandbox, but that doesn't stop the code from doing other things, like starting threads (which one of my requirements does not allow).  I thought was to scan the assembly once it's loaded into the sandbox, and determine if the `Thread` class is ever used.

I've done some initial [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693881/c-sharp-can-i-use-reflection-to-inspect-the-code-in-a-method) on using IL to determine that, but I'm wondering if there is an easier way than reconstructing the results of [`GetMethodBody`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getmethodbody(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/26588882/41071.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/).  You can inspect everything the code does at the bytecode level.