# How to get il of one method body with roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I want  to get il of one method in my c# source code file.I have opened solution  with roslyn and find the method symbol like below

```
Roslyn.Compilers.Common.ISymbol s=GetMethodSymbolAtPosition (30);
```

I have an ISymbol how get il now?

Comment: Compile the code, get the body. It's not like Roslyn can just compile one method in one source file without context :)

Comment: Why do you need the IL? What do you want to do with it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, the IL generation is entirely hidden inside the `Emit` call in Roslyn. But I'll give a simple to get you started.

Let's suppose you start of with an existing compilation:

```
var initial = CSharpCompilation.Create("Existing")
    .AddReferences(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location))
    .AddSyntaxTrees(SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree(@"    
        namespace Test
        {
            public class Program
            {
                public static void HelloWorld()
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine(""Hello World"");
                }
            }
        }"));    
var method = initial.GetSymbolsWithName(x => x == "HelloWorld").Single();
```

where `method` is your `ISymbol`. Then you can do following:

```
// 1. get source
var methodRef = method.DeclaringSyntaxReferences.Single();
var methodSource =  methodRef.SyntaxTree.GetText().GetSubText(methodRef.Span).ToString();

// 2. compile in-memory as script
var compilation = CSharpCompilation.CreateScriptCompilation("Temp")
    .AddReferences(initial.References)
    .AddSyntaxTrees(SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree(methodSource, CSharpParseOptions.Default.WithKind(SourceCodeKind.Script)));

using (var dll = new MemoryStream())
using (var pdb = new MemoryStream())
{
    compilation.Emit(dll, pdb);

    // 3. load compiled assembly
    var assembly = Assembly.Load(dll.ToArray(), pdb.ToArray());
    var methodBase = assembly.GetType("Script").GetMethod(method.Name, new Type[0]);

    // 4. get il or even execute
    var il = methodBase.GetMethodBody();
    methodBase.Invoke(null, null);
}
```

In a more complex case, you'd probably need to emit the entire/initial compilation, and get the generated method via reflection.

Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693881/c-sharp-can-i-use-reflection-to-inspect-the-code-in-a-method) to find out what you can do with the results of `GetMethodBody()`.

Comment: "Unfortunately, the IL generation is entirely hidden inside the Emit call in Roslyn." Do you happen to know where in Roslyn the IL is generated? (Roslyn is a huge program - I'm just getting started looking at it - and I'd like to try to tweak the IL generated for some C# statements.)

Comment: I get a `System.BadImageFormatException: Bad IL format.` exception when trying to use this, unfortunately. (.NET Core 3.1 on Linux)