# C# DeveloperCommandPrompt

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cmd, process

I want to call commands such as `msbuild`/`dumpbin` with Environment Variables which are set in `DevelopersCommandPrompt`.

I have no experience with C#, and I couldn't find a clean way to achieve this. What I thought of, was to first run Process `DevelopersCommandPrompt` and read `set` command output to retrieve all process environment variables and then call new Process, but this time with the dictionary of retrieved env variables.

But it turns out I cannot even get the `set` command result to work.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
            FileName = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\Common7\\Tools\\VsDevCmd.bat",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true
    };

        Process devCmd = new Process();
        devCmd.StartInfo = startInfo;
        devCmd.Start();

        devCmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("set");
        devCmd.StandardInput.Flush();
        devCmd.StandardInput.Close();
        devCmd.WaitForExit();
        Console.WriteLine(devCmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

I believe I'm doing something wrong (as when I change `set` to `dir` it doesn't work too). Unfortunately I have no clue what am I missing:)

Moreover if anyone has a smarter/cleaner solution for running Microsoft toolset from C# then I would love to hear it. :)

Thanks

Comment: VSC has a batch file to set it all up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**
I'm closing the thread.

@Guru Stron has found why I couldn't gather env variables from Developer Command Prompt. You can check his answer above, but it is just a bug in my code.

**Compiling**
If anyone is interested in just compiling c++ visual studio project from c# then I've found a solution here: https://gist.github.com/jeremybeavon/5736e0acbf3729092887

Make sure you add as references correct (not 4.0 version) of all Microsoft.Msbuild.* packages.

If you are interested in compiling c# project instead then I would recommend using https://github.com/daveaglick/Buildalyzer project.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `cmd.exe` as `FileName` and set `Arguments` to path to VS dev console bat file like this:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = @"cmd.exe",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        Arguments = @"""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"""
    };
```

Comment: Great! Now I also understand @Mark comment:)
I will not close this thread yet as maybe someone will come up with cleaner then mine solution. But yours fixes my problem:)

Comment: What part of toolset dou you actually need? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I would definitely like to compile C project with `msbuild`, but also recently I found out that I need a way to dissassembly program programitically and so I thought I would like to use `dumpbin` as well.

Comment: @RobD, have you thought about using [Roslyn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35745154/2501279)?