# Is it possible to check if a Property has a Setter that references another object?

Tags: c#, properties, getter-setter

In C#, is it possible to check if a Property has a Setter that references another object at runtime?

Here is some code:

```
private PropertyChanged _propertyChanged;
public string PropertyChangedName
{
    get
    {
        return _propertyChanged.Name;
    }
    set
    {
        _propertyChanged.Name = value;
    }
}
```

In the above code, the PropertyChangedName is referenced as part of the PropertyChanged object. When setting the PropertyChangedName, the _propertyChanged.Name is set.

Here is some code where the PropertyChangedName is not referenced as part of the PropertyChanged object:

```
private string _propertyChangedName;
public string PropertyChangedName
{
    get
    {
        return _propertyChangedName;
    }
    set
    {
        _propertyChangedName = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is the best way, however, it might help you:

```
// store the current state:
var valuesbefore = new List<object>();
foreach (var r in this.GetType().GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic))
    valuesbefore.Add(r.GetValue(this));

// change the value the specified property
PropertyChangedName = PropertyChangedName + "a"; 

//get the new state of the class:
var valuesnow = new List<object>();
foreach (var r in this.GetType().GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic))
    valuesnow.Add(r.GetValue(this));

// check for any change
bool equal = valuesbefore.SequenceEqual(valuesnow);
```

If *equal* is false, it means that you are dealing with a case in which the setter changes the value of private field. Note that special care is required when dealing with types other than string, int, etc.

Comment: Is it possible to perform the code you have posted at runtime?

Comment: Did you encounter any problems? Note that the logic is easy: Save a copy of the class, change the property, compare it with the saved copy and see what happened.

Comment: Your code is not viable as the code needs to be performed on many objects at runtime, without saving a copy of the class. Is there another possible way?

Comment: I forgot to add _.GetValue(this)_ of the FiledInfo. I corrected it.

Comment: Don't forget to replace _this.GetType()_ with the type you are dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) and subscribe to it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really tricky question. The `System.Reflection` library in .NET allows you to observe the class signatures (Types, Fields, Methods, etc), invoke them, and get their values; but not see within their body.

Read through the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693881/can-i-use-reflection-to-inspect-the-code-in-a-method) for some options to inspect the contents of methods.  (a Property is just a method -- two if you have both `get` and `set`)